# Are there any big junkyards near Indianapolis?

Tags: usa, automobiles, identify-this, indiana, indianapolis

Are there any big (and preferably abandoned) junkyards near Indianapolis, IN or Bloomington, IN?

I'm looking for something like this (not necessarily *that* big):

[image]

My research in Google and on Google Maps only gave some very small junkyards adjacent to auto parts stores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find two self-service junkyards in Indianapolis (none in Bloomington) which were large enough to bother with visiting. These allow you to enter for a small fee, find the parts you want, pull them out and then pay for those parts as you leave.

[U-Pull-&-Pay](https://upullandpay.com/indianapolis/home/) ([map](https://goo.gl/maps/JpYPUkeK8btL723s7)) is located north of downtown Indianapolis and has a $2 per person admission fee.

[Pull-A-Part](https://www.pullapart.com/locations/indianapolis/) ([map](https://goo.gl/maps/3qJTiuW5gX44fe2a9)) is in northeast Indianapolis and also has a $2 per person admission fee.

I found a few other junkyards but they were quite small and probably not worth the trouble if you are merely wanting to be a tourist. But it's fine to go to either of these yards, pay your $2 to get in, browse around and leave without buying anything else.

I wasn't able to find anything *closed* or *abandoned*, but I wouldn't recommend doing that anyway. It's potentially dangerous and could also get you in hot water with the police for trespassing. Going to one of the above yards, you'll see an active junkyard, have paid for the right to be there, and actually meet people who use the place.

Answer (score 1):

There is/was a sizeable junkyard associated with [Bloomington Auto Parts](http://bloomingtonautoparts.com), just north of Bloomington.  It was clearly visible from SR-37 back before the I-69 project, and while I no longer live in the area, I would be surprised if it had been moved since then.

[image]

Note that [the aerial imagery used by Google](https://goo.gl/maps/SEgQQ4De9KMuz2239) predates the I-69 project, and does not accurately show the roads in the vicinity.  (The map layer presumably does show these roads correctly.)  Also note that the location marked for Bloomington Auto Parts on Google Maps is approximately 2/3 mile south of where the junkyard itself is located.

(I have no affiliation with Bloomington Auto Parts.)

Comment: Is it supposed to be open to the public? According to Google Maps street view (from 2015), there are closed gates at the entrance to this junkyard (39°16'13.5"N 86°31'21.1"W).

Comment: Unclear.  The aerial imagery pretty clearly shows the gate open, and the business does appear to be in operation still.  But even then, it's possible that they don't want people poking around the junkyard unsupervised.  I'd give them a call or an e-mail, explain why you need access to the yard itself, and see what they say.

Comment: @user77409 It isn't the sort of junkyard where you go in and pick out parts yourself. You tell them what you are looking for and they go and get it for you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Actually I'm not looking for any parts. Someone who will be visiting the US just wants to see what an American junkyard looks like.